Beamer frame sizes not laying well with positions
I am trying to make a custom template such that there is a left-side grey panel can show points I wish to highlight and the white section to the right will give the description. I am using tcolorbox to achieve this.
I find that:

I am unable to bring the frametitle down by 0.5cm.
The subtitle disappears.
The white text panel refuses to go beyond 0.65\textwidth despite space being available.

Here is my MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % Load the tcolorbox package

% Right-justify frametitle
%\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\hfill\sc\insertframetitle}
\setbeamertemplate{framesubtitle}{\hfill\sc\insertframesubtitle}

% Define the custom sidebar using tcolorbox
\newcommand{\greybar}[1]{%
\vfill
\hspace{-1cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        arc=14pt,
        outer arc=5pt,
        colback=gray!20,
        colframe=gray!20,
        width=0.25\paperwidth, % Adjust width as needed
        height=0.85\paperheight, % Adjust height to match the slide height
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=2mm, % Doen't adjust distance from left edge
        top=2mm, % Doesn't adjust distance from top edge
        bottom=5mm, % Doesn't adjust distance from bottom edge 
    ]
    \raggedright % Ensure text is left-aligned
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\newcommand{\whitebar}[1]{%
\hspace{-0.3cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        arc=14pt,
        outer arc=5pt,
        colback=white,
        colframe=gray!20,
        width=0.65\paperwidth, % Adjust width as needed
        height=0.85\paperheight, % Adjust height to match the slide height
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=2mm, % Doen't adjust distance from left edge
        top=2mm, % Doesn't adjust distance from top edge
        bottom=5mm, % Doesn't adjust distance from bottom edge 
    ]
    \raggedright % Ensure text is left-aligned
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

% Title page setup
\title{Presentation Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{Random Date}

\begin{document}

% Title page
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

% Normal frames with custom layout
\begin{frame}[t] % Use plain option to remove header and footer
    \frametitle{First Slide}
    \framesubtitle{Some subtitle}
\greybar{Highlight this point.\\
This is super important}
\whitebar{General description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

And here is how the slide looks:



the frametitle template is responsible for inserting the whole frametitle complex including the subtitle. If you redefine it to only include the frametitle, you will loose the subtitle. Easiest to use the default template and change the font instead.

there are several missing % at the end of your lines. Each of them will add a space and your boxes won't fit besides each other if you make them wider

instead of using \hspace{-1cm} to force your box into the margin, you could change the text margins.



\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % Load the tcolorbox package

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.2cm,text margin right=0.2cm}

% Right-justify frametitle
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@fteright{}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]

% Define the custom sidebar using tcolorbox
\newcommand{\greybar}[1]{%
\vfill
%\hspace{-1cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        arc=14pt,
        outer arc=5pt,
        colback=gray!20,
        colframe=gray!20,
        width=0.25\textwidth, % Adjust width as needed
        height=0.75\paperheight, % Adjust height to match the slide height
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=2mm, % Doen't adjust distance from left edge
        top=2mm, % Doesn't adjust distance from top edge
        bottom=5mm, % Doesn't adjust distance from bottom edge 
    ]
    \raggedright % Ensure text is left-aligned
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\newcommand{\whitebar}[1]{%
%\hspace{-0.3cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        arc=14pt,
        outer arc=5pt,
        colback=white,
        colframe=gray!20,
        width=0.75\textwidth, % Adjust width as needed
        height=0.75\paperheight, % Adjust height to match the slide height
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=2mm, % Doen't adjust distance from left edge
        top=2mm, % Doesn't adjust distance from top edge
        bottom=5mm, % Doesn't adjust distance from bottom edge 
    ]
    \raggedright % Ensure text is left-aligned
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

% Title page setup
\title{Presentation Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{Random Date}

\begin{document}

% Normal frames with custom layout
\begin{frame}[t] % Use plain option to remove header and footer
    \frametitle{First Slide}
    \framesubtitle{Some subtitle}
\greybar{Highlight this point.\\
This is super important}%
\whitebar{General description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



This worked. Thank you. I must ask though; so I can learn, what resources can I use to better understand your code? In which context to use \makeatother and \makeatletter and which aspects of beamer you changed. Because the manual of beamer doesn't get into that.

The \makeatother ... \makeatletter allows one to use commands which have a @ in their name. In the code above, I wanted to redefine \beamer@fteright, so I had to wrap it in \makeatother ... \makeatletter because of the @ in the name. The purpose of the redefinition is to adjust the margins of the right aligned frame title.  With the beamer dev version on github, this should no longer be necessary, we changed the spacing for right aligned titles.
